# site collection url is same as root site after backup and restore

Tags: 2016, backup, restore, content

i have 1 web application with 1 site collection in 1 content DB. In order to restore some corrupted site data i have got the back up and restore the same db from past dates to dev environment which is mounted ok in dev in addtion to dev content db. I see the new restored db has site collection in it. Now when i browse the restored site collection url http://intranet-prod is the same as production site collection http://intranet-prod. How do i access the restored site collection ? Do i need to create new web application and mount the Content DB to it ? please help.

Answer (score 1):

A SiteCollection itself normally doesn't carry the full URL (http://intranet-prod/sites/site1), but only the relative URL (/sites/site1).

So if you restore to DEV, you have to open the site with the URL of the DEV WebApplication and the relative URL of the production site (e.g. http://intranet-dev/sites/site1).

You can get a List of existing sites via PowerShell `Get-SPSite -Limit all -WebApplication http://intranet-dev` to check where you can find your restored site.